# How to configure vsftpd with docker

Tags: docker, ftp, vsftpd

I have been trying to configure a simple ftp server using the following docker container:

https://hub.docker.com/r/fauria/vsftpd

I deploy the container on an amazon ec2 instance with ports open for 20 and 21.

my docker-compose is like this:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    vsftpd:
    image: fauria/vsftpd
    environment:
      - FTP_USER=myuser
      - FTP_PASS=mYp4sS
    ports:
      - 20:20
      - 21:21
    volumes: 
      - /var/app/ftp:/home/vsftpd
      - /var/log/ftp:/var/log/vsftpd
```

when starting docker I do get the following log and then nothing:

```
vsftpd  |   *************************************************
vsftpd  |   *                                               *
vsftpd  |   *    Docker image: fauria/vsftpd                *
vsftpd  |   *    https://github.com/fauria/docker-vsftpd    *
vsftpd  |   *                                               *
vsftpd  |   *************************************************
vsftpd  | 
vsftpd  |   SERVER SETTINGS
vsftpd  |   ---------------
vsftpd  |   ? FTP User: myuser
vsftpd  |   ? FTP Password: mYp4sS
vsftpd  |   ? Log file: /var/log/vsftpd/vsftpd.log
vsftpd  |   ? Redirect vsftpd log to STDOUT: No.
```

But when I try a ftp connection either with filezilla or event the cli ftp I keep getting a `ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server` issue.

How can I make the ftp server accessible?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is at port declaration in your docker-compose file, if you see in the example in the github repository, the statement with ip address and port is used, not only the port like you did before.

```
'3.6'
services:
    vsftpd:
    image: fauria/vsftpd
    environment:
        - FTP_USER=myuser
        - FTP_PASS=mYp4sS
    ports:
        - 0.0.0.0:20:20
        - 0.0.0.0:21:21
    volumes: 
        - /var/app/ftp:/home/vsftpd
        - /var/log/ftp:/var/log/vsftpd
```

[just in case look in the file](https://github.com/fauria/docker-vsftpd/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)